# Magento upgrade from 1.6.2 - php error when checking magento list-upgrades in SSH

Tags: php, arrays, magento, upgrade, ksort

i'm using SSH to upgrade from Magento 1.6.2 to latest version. When i enter the command ./mage list-upgrades I get repeated lines of the following before i see the upgrade results:

PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have at least 1 element in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsitename/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 227
PHP Warning:  ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /var/www/vhosts/mywebsitename/httpdocs/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Rest.php on line 228

i have the latest version of php installed (i think) and checked online to find the original rest.php script and it looks identical.
Any ideas?